# Getting CLOB completed from DB table via SQL in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, clob

I have a table (actually a view) with few varchar2 fields. Say, 
v_report(id, name, profile_id, profile_name);

I need to collect **id**-groupped data into a string. So, I do:

```
SELECT
   id,
   'Name: ' || clobagg(DISTINCT name)
   || ' Profile_name: ' || clobagg(DISTINCT profile_name)
   as description
FROM
   v_report
GROUP BY
   id
```

clobagg is like described here:  https://community.oracle.com/thread/2264483

*(especially use clobagg not stragg due to it's returning value clob able to store >4000 chars)*

It works fine when concatenated profile string isn't too large. But if it is i get fair Oracle exception:

```
ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 7680, maximum: 4000)
```

Is there some way out? I mean something like DBMS_LOB.APPEND function but available to call via SQL. Or any other way to concat many varchar2 strings into a large CLOB string w/o length limit.

Thanks in advance.

Pavel.

Comment: Kamil G., sorry, have you read the question?

Comment: Sorry, but yes? Otherwise I wouldn't even consider voting. It's a "possible" duplicate vote.

Comment: @KamilG. - if you read the question and answer more closely, you will see that it had to do with READING FROM a BLOB. The solution offered there has nothing to do with the problem presented here.

Comment: @AvoiDFaTE - so, are you able to create the CLOB's in the first place (without concatenation)? If you are, then what you are missing is wrapping the literals (and any other VARCHAR2 values you may have) within `to_clob()`. Good luck!

Comment: @mathguy I stand corrected, thanks.

Comment: @KamilG. - no problem, thank you for following up!

Comment: @mathguy thank you! It works great. Also I faced here with another problem but out of this question!

Comment: OK, if that was the answer, I will post it as an Answer for future readers. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*NOTE*: initially posted as a Comment, but offered as an Answer now, since the OP has confirmed that this was, in fact, the problem.

So, are you able to create the `CLOB`s in the first place (without concatenation)? If you are, then what you are missing is wrapping the literals (and any other `VARCHAR2` values you may have) within `to_clob()`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Minor addition.

After this solving I got same error in clobagg;
So I had to modify it to set input parameter as varchar2 (to enable DISTINCT clause work) and the returning value is CLOB.

So, as far it may be useful here it is:

```
create or replace
TYPE             CLOBAGG_TYPE AS OBJECT 
( 
 text clob,
                              static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(
                                                                      sctx in out clobagg_type
                                                                     )
                                return number,
                              member function ODCIAggregateIterate(
                                                                   self  in out clobagg_type,
                                                                   value in     varchar2
                                                                  )
                                return number,
                              member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(
                                                                     self        in     clobagg_type,
                                                                     returnvalue    out clob,
                                                                     flags       in     varchar2
                                                                    )
                                return number,
                              member function ODCIAggregateMerge(
                                                                 self in out clobagg_type,
                                                                 ctx2 in     clobagg_type
                                                                )
                                return number
)

create or replace
TYPE BODY             CLOBAGG_TYPE AS

static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(
                                              sctx in out clobagg_type
                                             )
        return number
        is
        begin
            sctx := clobagg_type(null) ;
            return ODCIConst.Success ;
      end;
      member function ODCIAggregateIterate(
                                           self  in out clobagg_type,
                                           value in     varchar2
                                          )
        return number
        is
        begin
            self.text := self.text || ', ' || value;
            return ODCIConst.Success;
      end;
      member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(
                                             self        in     clobagg_type,
                                             returnvalue    out clob,
                                             flags       in     varchar2
                                            )
        return number
        is
        begin
            returnValue := ltrim(self.text,', ');
            return ODCIConst.Success;
        end;
      member function ODCIAggregateMerge(
                                         self in out clobagg_type ,
                                         ctx2 in     clobagg_type
                                        )
        return number
        is
        begin
            self.text := self.text || ctx2.text;
            return ODCIConst.Success;
        end;

END;


create or replace
FUNCTION             CLOBAGG(
                   input varchar2
                  ) RETURN clob 
    deterministic
    parallel_enable
    aggregate using clobagg_type;
```